# Using Services to create a Speech to Text Function with Vosk?

Tags: twilio, vosk

wanted to get some additional opinions on a project.

I'm attempting to create a system which will gather the dialog from a call commenced by Twilio Studio and transcribe it. I then intend to push the now transcribed dialog to my CRM.

I found a helpful article on speech to text with the use of Vosk; https://www.twilio.com/blog/transcribe-phone-calls-text-real-time-twilio-vosk - however, I *think* the article assumes that this will be done with the use of an external application. So, my question is; could this be possibly developed with the use of Twilio Services and leveraged within Studio?

If not, I *could* develop a web app to connect everything together, but would rather everything be housed within Twilio as I'm a novice developer and developing this app externally sounds like a rather over complex solution to this project.

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Nothing attempted yet, still in the early research stage of this project.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, Twilio does not offer its own Speech-to-Text engine. However, you can use media streams to forward the audio track to any engine out there on the internet.

This [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/live-transcribing-phone-calls-using-twilio-media-streams-and-google-speech-text) uses Google's engine, for example.

The advantage of such a hosted service is that you neither need to worry about the model nor manage the server. If you want to do 100% serverless, then you could run the entire thing on [Twilio Serverless](https://www.twilio.com/docs/labs/serverless-toolkit/general-usage#create-a-project).

Comment: PS: If you found this answer helpful, please go ahead and use the "checkmark" button to accept it.